# Created jQuery Elements are not in jQuery Style

Tags: jquery, styles

I'm a newbie to all that JavaScript and jQuery-Stuff. Please excuse any stupid faults of my coding or my dirty style. I'm glad for all constructive feedback from your experienced side.

I try to dynamically add some jQuery elements, like some new select menus. In my example the user shall decide how many cars he wants to customize and based on that I want to create one new select menu for each car chosen.

I got it to work that if the users choses "2 cars" jQuery will add two new select menus. But my problem is that these menus are not in jQuery-Style anymore.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it also possible to add new menus in a "for-loop" based on the choses number of cars?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#select-choice-1').live( "change", function(event, ui) {
        var valuee = $(this).val();

        if (valuee == '2') ($('<label for="select-choice-2" class="select">Color of car #1</label>' +
                                          '<select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2">'+
                                          '<option value="red">red</option>'+
                                          '<option value="blue">blue</option>'+
                                          '</select><br><br>' +
                              '<label for="select-choice-3" class="select">Color of car #2</label>' +
                                          '<select name="select-choice-3" id="select-choice-3">'+
                                          '<option value="green">green</option>'+
                                          '<option value="yellow">yellow</option>'+
                                          '</select>').appendTo('#site'));
        if (valuee == '3') ($('<h1>Test</h1>').appendTo('#site'));

    });
    </script>
```

And here is the html page:

```
<div id="site" data-role="fieldcontain">    

    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Number of cars</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>


    </div><!-- "site" -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery-Style"?

Comment: It just looks as plain html style. No drop-shadow, just an old-school select-field like that: http://www.vaannila.com/images/struts1/HtmlSelectTag1Pic1.gif

Comment: If by jQuery-style you mean jQuery-ui styling then you'll need to add to your html the same classes jQuery ui does.

Comment: How do you want to make this?

Comment: If you want to have your own styles for it then add css and add those classes to these elements

Comment: Your css is probably selecting `select-choice-1` then. It is hard to tell unless you post your css.

Comment: Also, your JS is kinda funky :) weird stuff going on there

Comment: What do you mean with "funky"? ;) I want to evaluate the user choice and based on that, create the numbers of new menus? How would you do that?

Comment: Instead of adding the menus dynamically, put them in the HTML with `display: none;` style, and use `show()` in jQuery to make them visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('#site').delegate("#select-choice-1", "change", function(event, ui) {
           var valuee = $(this).val();
           var constructhtml = '';
             if (valuee == '2') {
               constructhtml +='<label for="select-choice-2" class="select">Color of car #1</label>' +   '<select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2">'+ '<option value="red">red</option>'+ '<option value="blue">blue</option>'+ '</select><br><br>' + '<label for="select-choice-3" class="select">Color of car #2</label>' + '<select name="select-choice-3" id="select-choice-3">'+ '<option value="green">green</option>'+ '<option value="yellow">yellow</option>'+ '</select>';
             }else if (valuee == '3') {
               constructhtml +='<h1>Test</h1>';
             }
    $('#site').append(constructhtml);
     });
```

OP's need to created a dynamically added select menu

Put this div at thwe very bottom of your page

```
<div id="selectcontainer"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){

var str = '';
str+='<select>';
   for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    str+='<option value='"+i+"'>'"+i+"'</option>';

  }   
str+='</select>';
 $('#selectcontainer').html(str);
});
```

Comment: May be some CSS issue with the design..i added some tweaking(removed `live` and added formatting)

Comment: I just took the original jquery.css and did not change anything. I dont want any new style, I just want the new select menu to look like an ordinary jquery select menu

Comment: If you use firebug and Mozilla..analyse the select menu and see which style is applying for it

Comment: firebug isn't opening on that testpage

Comment: OK then remove any classes for that select menu and in jquery.css comment styles relating to select ..and try

Comment: It's simply not working here :( Could you provide me with a simple solution how you'd solve that problem of dynamically adding new select menus?